# Getting a sharable link to a file in a shared dropbox folder

Tags: dropbox

1. Create a folder "fruit" and share it. Now you have a link, something like 
   https://www.dropbox.com/sh/123/456-789
2. Add apple.png and orange.png in "fruit"
3. You'd think apple.png will be available as https://www.dropbox.com/sh/123/456-789/apple.png, but it's not.

Opening the folder link in the browser, does provide me with links to the files; but I don't want to have to do it for every file.

Am I missing something very obvious?

How can I get links to apple.png and orange.png in the shared folder? without having to click on web links or Explorer/Finder menus.

Comment: Tried right click the file and select copy link location? That seems to work here. ex: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c9y3o0conv1laxe/AAB80ETzoXT7FBbi8X7r0iGMa?dl=0

Comment: @Sathya that works, but it doesn't help. I don't want to click anything, my edit makes it pretty clear. In your example, note that each linked file gets a different link.

Comment: Links will be autogenerated in dropbox , to customize them please check the steps provided in the link http://hostlater.com/2014/04/dropbox-custom-domain-name-url-2246/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the folder "fruit" in your Public Folder, you are able to access files in this manner using your Public Folder's URL.

#### In the Dropbox web app:

1. Create a file called 'test' in your Public Folder
2. Right-click 'test' and select 'Copy public link...'
3. Use that link as your base - it should look like https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12345678/test.txt
4. You can now use this base link to reference other files in your public folder:
   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12345678/fruit/apple.png

#### Take Note:

- Although this works for files within a public folder, it doesn't provide a folder listing - that is, the link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12345678/fruit won't work. To link to folders, use the 'Share...' menu option.*
- A "Public Folder" is only available in accounts created before October 4, 2012 - or Pro users that have enabled it. (https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/16)

Comment: Thanks, this works. Although it should be noted (perhaps edit your answer?) that it **only** works with the public folder, and accounts created after October 2012 don't have a public folder (see https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/16). Paid accounts can enable the public folder, though.

Comment: Glad to hear - and thanks, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have first login on Dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/
2. Click on New Folder. Please check this image.
   [image]
3. Textbox in add folder name. Example:- "fruit"
   [image]
4. Click on your folder name.
5. Your folder in add image , files, etc ...
6. Click on Upload file.
   [image]
7. Click on choose files button on & upload images , files , etc...
8. Click on right click your folder "fruit" and Share link.
   [image]
9. Enter send email address on email text-box in. 
   [image]
10. Click on "Send" Button.